# Poor performance of Neo4j Cypher query for transitive closure

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph with ~89K nodes and ~1.2M relationships, and am trying to get the transitive closure of a single node via the following Cypher query:

```
start n=NODE(<id of a single node of interest>)
match (n)-[*1..]->(m)
where has(m.name)
return distinct m.name
```

Unfortunately, this query goes away and doesn't seem to come back (although to be fair I've only given it about an hour of execution time at this point).

Any suggestions on ways to optimise what I've got here, or better ways to achieve the requirement?

Notes:

- Neo4J v2.0.0 (installed via Homebrew).
- Mac OSX 10.8.5
- Oracle Java 1.7.0_51
- 8GB physical RAM (neo4j JVM assigned whatever the default is)
- Database is hosted on an SSD volume.
- Query is submitted via the admin web UI's "Data browser".
- "name" is an auto-indexed field.
- CPU usage is fairly low - averaging around 20% of 8 cores.
- I haven't gotten into the weeds of profiling the Neo4J server yet - my first attempt locked up VisualVM.

Comment: Do you have cycles in your graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's probably a combinatorial explosion of path, care to try this?

```
start n=NODE(<id of a single node of interest>),m=node:node_auto_index("name:*")
match shortestPath((n)-[*]->(m))
return m.name
```

without shortest-path it would look like that, but as you are only interested in the reachable nodes from `n` the above should be good enough.

```
start n=NODE(<id of a single node of interest>),m=node:node_auto_index("name:*")
match (n)-[*]->(m)
return distnct m.name
```

Comment: Thanks Michael - that worked.  The query took about 10 minutes to run (producing ~3.2K results), but that's still a vast improvement over my original query.

Answer (score 0):

Try query - https://code.google.com/p/gueryframework/ - this is a standalone library but is has a neo4j adapter. I.e., you will have to rewrite your queries in the query format.

Better support for transitive closure was one of the main reasons for developing query, we mainly use this in software analysis tools where we need reachability / pattern analysis (e.g., the antipattern queries in http://xplrarc.massey.ac.nz/ are computed using query).

There is a brief discussion about this in the neo4j google group:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/neo4j/jens/neo4j/n69ksEJxDtQ/29DNKyWKur4J

and an (older, not maintained) project with some benchmarking code:

https://code.google.com/p/graph-query-benchmarks/

Cheers, Jens